# Images of real coins used as "rewards" in games

Tags: software, currency

There are some educational math "games" for androids targeted at pre-highschool students.

Since their goal is to make learning fun, they some times include rewards which are visually appealing to promote certain actions (repeating exercises, coming back for more, playing regularly, etc). Those rewards are not purchasable,  tradable or exchangeable, and are purely there for cosmetic purposes.

Some of those rewards are depicted as real images of coins.
For example answering correctly a difficult question could give +1 to the count of the user's gold coins.

An "awarded" coin could look something like [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stater_Zeus_Lampsacus_CdM.jpg).

Could this be interpreted as false advertisement? Since someone could mistakenly assume that by playing the game he can win 100 gold coins aging 2500+ years.

**What is the general practice when it comes to "rewards" being depicted as monetary items?**

Some extremely popular games contain the following in [their Terms Of Use](http://plarium.com/en/terms-of-use/) that their virtual currency have no real currency value.

But then again, their coins are not photos of real coins, they are just  drawings.

Comment: Also, regarding the "no real currency value", *actual* ancient coins arguably no longer have any value *as currency*, but as historical artifacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> someone could ... mistakenly assume that by playing the game he can win 100 gold coins aging 2500+ years.

Yes *someone* could, if they were an idiot, however, that is not the legal criteria. The legal criteria is if a [reasonable person](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Reasonable+Person) would.